# How to recognize a zebra crossing from top view using OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, template-matching

How to recognize a [zebra crossing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_crossing) from top view using OpenCV?
It is not a straight zebra crossing - it has some twists and turns.
I have some ideas:

1. parallel line detection, but the available techniques only work to find straight parallel lines, not curved
2. template matching to match a template of back to back white and black stripes, but it becomes tedious since I can't find any pattern matching techniques with scaling and rotation

Comment: You should probably post a picture and description of a [zebra crossing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_crossing), as this term is not well known in most countries.

Comment: So it's a square wave.  That should show up in the 2D FFT as strong spikes at the frequency of the stripes and its harmonics.  Something like Haar wavelet that specifically looks for square waves might be better?